# Problemas para instalar modulo Kociemba de Python

Tags: python, librería, instalacion

Para un proyecto necesito instalar el modulo de Kociemba que es un modulo con funciones para resolver un cubo Rubik's. Cuento con la version 3.9.2 y cuando corro `pip install kociemba` me aparece un error que por lo que he investigado parece ser que mi version de Python es muy nueva. En realidad agradeceria si alguien me podria decir como hacerle para poder utilizar esta libreria.

Comment: Podrías agregar el mensaje de error que te muestra, así es más fácil ayudarte. En la página de la librería no detalla ningún caso especial: [https://pypi.org/project/kociemba/

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar vendría genial que pusieras el error que te da, para que se te pueda ayudar de una manera mas directa.

Por otro lado he leído un poco sobre la librería que comentas, en su propia web indican que según el sistema operativo donde la estas instalando, antes de instalarla se tienen que instalar unas dependencias (en este enlace aparece esa información que te estoy comentando https://pypi.org/project/kociemba/ )

Por último he probado a instalar la librería `kociemba` en un entorno limpio. Para ello he ejecutado:

```
docker run -ti python:3.9.2 bash
```

Dentro del contenedor docker que se levanta con python:3.9.2, he probado a instalar la librería y se ha instalado sin problema.

Siguiendo este método podrías ya tener un entorno de desarrollo con la librería instalada.

Y por último el que me haya instalado bien la librería me hace pensar que el problema que te da al instalar es por alguna dependencia que le falta.